# How to solve these errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, runtimeexception

I am developing 2-D game on Unity. But I am getting some errors. And I dont know how to solve these. I am newbie and taking refrence from some links. Maybe I am creating checkpoints, spawnpoints, deathzone thats why getting errors.

PlayerRespawn.js-

```
var Player : GameObject;
var spawnPoint: Transform;

function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider) {
Destroy(other.gameObject);
var P: GameObject = Instantiate(Player,spawnPoint.position,Quaternion.identity);
var sf=Camera.main.GetComponent(SmoothFollow);
sf.target=P.transform;
}
```

SmoothFollow.js-

```
var target : Transform;
// The distance in the x-z plane to the target
var distance = 10.0;
// the height we want the camera to be above the target
var height = 5.0;
// How much we 
var heightDamping = 2.0;
var rotationDamping = 3.0;

// Place the script in the Camera-Control group in the component menu
@script AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Smooth Follow")


function LateUpdate () {
    // Early out if we don't have a target
    if (!target)
        return;

    // Calculate the current rotation angles
    var wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
    var wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;

    var currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
    var currentHeight = transform.position.y;

    // Damp the rotation around the y-axis
    currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle (currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    // Damp the height
    currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp (currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    // Convert the angle into a rotation
    var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, currentRotationAngle, 0);

    // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
    // distance meters behind the target
    transform.position = target.position;
    transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;

    // Set the height of the camera
    transform.position.y = currentHeight;

    // Always look at the target
    transform.LookAt (target);
}
```

And the errors I am getting are-

```
NullReferenceException
PlayerRespawn.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/scripts/PlayerRespawn.js:8)
```

Comment: Maybe some javascript files are missing that you should add to Assets folder.

Comment: And how to know what javascript files are missing?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

var sf=Camera.main.GetComponent(SmoothFollow);

check if the SmoothFollow component has been added to the Main Camera. Probably the problem is that after this statement, var sf is null.

Comment: when i am running the project then according to PlayerRespawn script, my player had died and then create new player but player can not access the smoothfollow script.

Comment: and occur missing reference exceptions

Comment: I don't understand your comments. Can you clarify them?

Comment: Actually I create SpawnPoints,Checkpoints and Deathzone.when i am running my project then my character is running and get spawnpoints and checkpoints .But when my character jumps over the Deathzone then running project is getting pause and character is not running means constant manner. and occurs these errors like  ("NullReferenceException
PlayerRespawn.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/MyScripts/PlayerRespawn.js:8)"
             It has PlayerRespawn.js script and smoothfollow.js.